# Can't use EF Core3.1 in .NET Framework4.8 project

Tags: entity-framework-core

We have a project which is a class libary, it's based on .NET Standard 2.0, let's call it LibraryA. This LibraryA project has a package reference to "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite (3.1.6)". We published this LibraryA with "dotnet publish [project path] --no-build -o [output] -c [configuration]".

Then there will be two different applications: one is based on .net Core 3.1, let's call it Application_Core; the other is based on .net Framework 4.8, let's call it Application_Framework.

The LibraryA can be properly loaded and execute in Application_Core (The Application_Core also references "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite"), but it can't run in Application_Framework. We get an error when it runs in Application_Framework, the error message says:

> *System.TypeLoadException: Method 'DisposeAsync' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' from assembly
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.6.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation. --->
> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'DisposeAsync' in type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' from assembly
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.6.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.*

if the Application_Framework also references "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite (3.1.6)" then it works. Unfornately we can't let the Application_Framework references "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite (3.1.6)" because of some reason.

Is this required that the application (e.g. Application_Core, Application_Framework) also needs reference "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" if the application wants to properly load a library which uses "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" to persit data?

Is there any other way which doesn't require application (Application_Core, Application_Framework) to reference "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" but still can properly load and run libary like LibraryA?

Thanks